# Can I burn FLV files to DVD

Tags: video, flv, dvd

I want to burn 3 flv videos to DVD, I have Nero but I not sure if the dvd will read the videos! because I have tried the flv videos with USB direct to TV but it didn't work, so now I want to burn them to DVD and watch the videos through DVD but I am not sure if the FLV videos will be converted properly so the DVD player in my TV will read them.
Do I have to convert the videos to some other format and then burn them to DVD or I just need to burn them to DVD with nero directly?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you trying to turn them into a proper DVD i.e. MPEG-2 or do you want them converted to some other format so that your DVD player will read the files and play them from the disk?

Comment: yes I want to know the best way to burn the flv files to DVD so my dvd player on the TV to read them because the TV doesnt read the FLV files

Comment: why dont you just try hitting the burn button ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burning as data disc will bring unchanged FLV files onto your CD. I don't know whether your DVD player can playback FLV, mine cannot (though it's a rather old one).

Another option would be to burn as Video DVD. You can use e.g. Nero Vision to author a "real" Video DVD, it should convert the files to the appropriate format

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may refer to [this](http://www.best-dvd-burning-software.com/how-to-burn-avi-divx-movie-to-playable-dvd.html) step by step guide, it will show you how to convert and burn flv video to DVD to play on normal DVD player.